# Desktop synchronization client my SMB server

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-synchronization, smb

I'm looking for a client that is similar to the OneDrive client. Syncs files between a server and Windows folder **but with [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)**. When I delete files on the server or folder they will move to windows' recycling bin.

I use Windows 10.